# AWS EC2 SSH with Private key to incorrect instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've setup a new EC2 Instance in AWS with a Private Key (downloaded and added to my ~/.ssh folder).

However, once the EC2 Instance has started, I try to ssh to that instance "a.a.a.a" public IP using the Private Key, however it logs me in to a different IP/instance.

Is there an ssh or private key cache of some sort I don't know about, or howcome I get ssh'd into a different EC2 Instance (in a different subnet)?

Comment: Double check the IP address you're connecting to. The private key plays no part in the connection to the instance. It only authenticates you and grants you access. So if you are connecting to the wrong instance, then the IP address is wrong.

Comment: Or, you're connecting to the correct instance, but you think it's the wrong instance.

Comment: I've checked and i'm definitely connecting to the new public IP address that is assigned to the new instance I created. We also tried connecting to the public dns name. I can get in, but it just sends me to another ec2 instance?

Comment: .ssh $ ssh -i "<key>.pem"<name>@<ec2-public-dns>

sends me to this:

[<name>@ip-<private ip of different ec2 instance> ~]$

Comment: Do a `shutdown -h now` from inside the instance and see which one stops in the AWS management console.

Comment: The following is the command that confirms private/public ip address on ec2 instances. 1. `$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`, 2. `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`. Is the instance still incorrect?

Comment: Tag all your VPC resources(all your subnet, secgroup,etc) and EC2 resoruces  Then reinspect your VPC setting and EC2 instance subnet . I used to make the same mistake and launch instance in wrong AZ subnet. Reinspect the Tag name of subnet just take me minutes to find out the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of guessing, do this. Once you ssh into the instance, invoke `ec2metadata` which will list among other data, the **private ip** and **public ip** (if it is assigned one) of the instance.

**/usr/bin/ec2metadata**

```
~$ ec2metadata
ami-id: ami-xxxxx
...
availability-zone: us-east-1a
...
instance-id: i-8080abcd
instance-type: m3.medium
...
local-ipv4: 10.2.1.40
...
public-hostname: ec2-23-64-195-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com
public-ipv4: 23.64.195.76
...
```

In case you do not find `ec2metadata`, download it:

```
$ wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2metadata/ec2-metadata
```

[EC2 Instance Metadata Query Tool](https://aws.amazon.com/items/1825?externalID=1825)

Comment: Unfortunately, not all Linux distros have `ec2metadata`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have already found solution, if not, you may consider trying below.

In your Mac/Windows there should be a file called '/xxx/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts' and please try to find entries of both IP's and remove those lines (These lines are added when you are trying to SSH to new instance. So there could be some conflict due to the old entries). I had faced similar issues and I did and it was working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can still get all meta-data or user-data of the instance by doing simple http request using curl/wget inside your instance:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

It should return all keys that you might be interested in getting its value like the following:

```
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
kernel-id
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
```

Now get only the key/data you want by specifying its name, the following will help distinguish your instance(s):

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac
```

To know more about EC2 Metadata, you can check http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-get-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata/